# P/Invoke struct off by 32 bits?

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

Im wrapping pjsip (C-lib) in c#.

My calls are as follow

```
var account = new pjsua_acc_config();
Accounts.pjsua_acc_config_default(account);
```

Which gets pivoked through this;

```
[DllImportAttribute("pjsua.dll", EntryPoint = "pjsua_acc_config_default", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, PreserveSig = true)]
public static extern void pjsua_acc_config_default([In, Out] pjsua_acc_config cfg);
```

which maps to

```
PJ_DEF(void) pjsua_acc_config_default(pjsua_acc_config *cfg)
```

Here *cfg is 0x00a5e8a8

next call is to use default config to add account, so i call

```
int id = Constants.PJSUA_INVALID_ID;
Accounts.pjsua_acc_add(account, 1, ref id);
```

which gets pivoked through this;

```
[DllImportAttribute("pjsua.dll", EntryPoint = "pjsua_acc_add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, PreserveSig = true)]
public static extern int pjsua_acc_add([In, Out]pjsua_acc_config acc_cfg, int is_default, ref int p_acc_id);
```

which maps to

```
PJ_DEF(pj_status_t) pjsua_acc_add( const pjsua_acc_config *cfg,                    int is_default, int *p_acc_id)
```

Here *cfg is 0x00a5e888, off by 32 bits. They should point to the same address since it the same object.

Howerer, if i change this

```
public static extern void pjsua_acc_config_default([In, Out] pjsua_acc_config cfg);
```

into

```
public static extern void pjsua_acc_config_default([In, Out] pjsua_acc_config cfg, pjsua_acc_config dummy1, pjsua_acc_config dummy2);
```

The addreses get aligned, anyone knows what can be causing this?

Comment: Hard to read.  In general: no, objects most certainly don't have stable pointers.  Not with a garbage collector moving them around.  Or with the pinvoke marshaller creating a copy of them, the somewhat more likely reason for a 32-bit offset.  Make sure that the C code isn't storing that pointer, that will be very very bad.

Comment: I _create_ the _class_ pjsua_acc_config, pjsip fills it up. I change stuff and send it to the add function. I need it to be the same exact object because the list implementation in pjsip check if a list on the object is empty by looking at a &list-node == &list-node->next.

Comment: That sounds very unhealthy.  Use Marshal.AllocHGlobal() to allocate unmanaged memory and Marshal.StructureToPtr() to initialize it.  That's a stable pointer that you can pass by declaring the argument as IntPtr.  How you are going to clean it up is a strong // todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, much help to Hans Passant first answer, except for manual marshal i changed the pinvoke declarations to IntPtr.

```
var account = new pjsua_acc_config();
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(typeof(pjsua_acc_config));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(account, ptr, false);
Accounts.pjsua_acc_config_default(ptr);
Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, account);

... make my changes to object ...

Marshal.StructureToPtr(account, ptr, false);

int id = Constants.PJSUA_INVALID_ID;
Accounts.pjsua_acc_add(ptr, 1, ref id);
```